# Allow only numbers and dot in script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

Am using this javascript for restrict users to type only numbers and only one dot as decimal separator.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(txt)
        {
            if(event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58 || event.keyCode == 46)
            {
               var txtbx=document.getElementById(txt);
               var amount = document.getElementById(txt).value;
               var present=0;
               var count=0;

               if(amount.indexOf(".",present)||amount.indexOf(".",present+1));
               {
              // alert('0');
               }

              /*if(amount.length==2)
              {
                if(event.keyCode != 46)
                return false;
              }*/
               do
               {
               present=amount.indexOf(".",present);
               if(present!=-1)
                {
                 count++;
                 present++;
                 }
               }
               while(present!=-1);
               if(present==-1 && amount.length==0 && event.keyCode == 46)
               {
                    event.keyCode=0;
                    //alert("Wrong position of decimal point not  allowed !!");
                    return false;
               }

               if(count>=1 && event.keyCode == 46)
               {

                    event.keyCode=0;
                    //alert("Only one decimal point is allowed !!");
                    return false;
               }
               if(count==1)
               {
                var lastdigits=amount.substring(amount.indexOf(".")+1,amount.length);
                if(lastdigits.length>=2)
                            {
                              //alert("Two decimal places only allowed");
                              event.keyCode=0;
                              return false;
                              }
               }
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                    event.keyCode=0;
                    //alert("Only Numbers with dot allowed !!");
                    return false;
            }

        }

    </script>

<td align="right">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQ1gTarget" runat="server" Width="30px" CssClass="txtbx" MaxLength="6" onkeypress="return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(this);"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

But the onkeypress(this) event returns object required error in that function at this place

```
var amount = document.getElementById(txt).value;
```

What's my mistake here?

Comment: You can try this: onkeypress="return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(event);"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using this:

`onkeypress="return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(this);"`

You should use this:

`onkeypress="return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(this.id);"`

Answer (score 75):

This is a great place to use regular expressions.

By using a regular expression, **you can replace all that code with just one line.**

You can use the following *regex* to validate your requirements:

`[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*`

In other words: zero or more numeric characters, followed by zero or one period(s),  followed by zero or more numeric characters.

You can replace your code with this:

```
function validate(s) {
    var rgx = /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/;
    return s.match(rgx);
}
```

**That code can replace your entire function!**

Note that you have to escape the period with a backslash (otherwise it stands for 'any character').

For more reading on using regular expressions with javascript, check this out:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

You can also test the above regex here:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

---

Explanation of the regex used above:

- The brackets mean "*any character inside these brackets*." You can use a hyphen (like above) to indicate a range of chars.
- The `*` means "*zero or more of the previous expression*."
- `[0-9]*` means "*zero or more numbers*"
- The backslash is used as an escape character for the period, because period usually stands for "*any character*."
- The `?` means "*zero or one of the previous character*."
- The `^` represents the beginning of a string.
- The `$` represents the end of a string.
- Starting the regex with `^` and ending it with `$` ensures that the *entire* string adheres to the regex pattern.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is matches() supposed to be match()?

Comment: Not a regex expert, but I had to use /^[0-9-]*\.?[0-9]*$/  in order to match negative numbers. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you're looking to not match the dot alone ("."), replace the first asterisk (*) with a plus (+)

Answer (score 25):

Use Jquery instead. Add a decimal class to your textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="decimal" value="" />
```

Use this code in your JS. It checks for multiple decimals and also restrict users to type only numbers.

```
$('.decimal').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(val)){
         val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
         if(val.split('.').length>2) 
             val =val.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    }
    $(this).val(val); 
});​
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2YW8g/

Hope it helps.

Comment: this doesn't work fine. Allowed multiple decimals. https://www.screencast.com/t/s43DpVAhw

Answer (score 17):

Just add the code below in your input text:

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode == 46 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)'
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
function isNumberKey(evt,id)
{
 try{
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  
        if(charCode==46){
            var txt=document.getElementById(id).value;
            if(!(txt.indexOf(".") > -1)){
 
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) )
            return false;

        return true;
 }catch(w){
  alert(w);
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this.id)" type="text" name="txtChar">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="text" class="decimal" value="" />
$('.decimal').keypress(function(evt){
    return (/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/).test($(this).val()+evt.key);
});
```

I think this simple solution may be.

Comment: This fails when the input is "123...122", it ignores the dot if put together

Answer (score 3):

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 46 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

you should use this function and write the properties of this element ;

**HTML Code:**

```
<input id="deneme" data-mini="true" onKeyPress="return isNumber(event)" type="text"/>`
```

Answer (score 2):

This works best for me.

I also apply a currency formatter on blur where the decimal part is rounded at 2 digits just in case after validating with parseFloat.

The functions that get and set the cursor position are from Vishal Monpara's blog. I also do some nice stuff on focus with those functions. You can easily remove 2 blocks of code where 2 decimals are forced if you want and get rid of the set/get caret functions.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return numericValidation(this,event);" />
<script language="JavaScript">
    function numericValidation(obj,evt) {
        var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility

        var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;        

        if (charCode == 46) { //one dot
            if (obj.value.indexOf(".") > -1)
                return false;
            else {
                //---if the dot is positioned in the middle give the user a surprise, remember: just 2 decimals allowed
                var idx = doGetCaretPosition(obj);
                var part1 = obj.value.substr(0,idx),
                    part2 = obj.value.substring(idx);

                if (part2.length > 2) {
                    obj.value = part1 + "." + part2.substr(0,2);
                    setCaretPosition(obj, idx + 1);
                    return false;
                }//---

                //allow one dot if not cheating
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) { //just numbers
            return false;
        }

        //---just 2 decimals stubborn!
        var arr = obj.value.split(".") , pos = doGetCaretPosition(obj);

        if (arr.length == 2 && pos > arr[0].length && arr[1].length == 2)                               
            return false;
        //---

        //ok it's a number
        return true;
    }

    function doGetCaretPosition (ctrl) {
        var CaretPos = 0;   // IE Support
        if (document.selection) {
        ctrl.focus ();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();
            Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);
            CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
        }
        // Firefox support
        else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
            CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
        return (CaretPos);
    }

    function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos){
        if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
        {
            ctrl.focus();
            ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
        }
        else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
            var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

try This Code

```js
var check = function(evt){

var data = document.getElementById('num').value;
if((evt.charCode>= 48 && evt.charCode <= 57) || evt.charCode== 46 ||evt.charCode == 0){
if(data.indexOf('.') > -1){
 if(evt.charCode== 46)
  evt.preventDefault();
}
}else
evt.preventDefault();
};

document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('keypress',check);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num" value="" />



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function numericValidation(txtvalue) {
        var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
        var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (!(document.getElementById(txtvalue.id).value))
         {
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        else {
               var val = document.getElementById(txtvalue.id).value;
            if(charCode==46 || (charCode > 31 && (charCode > 47 && charCode < 58)) )
             {
                var points = 0;            
                points = val.indexOf(".", points);                    
                if (points >= 1 && charCode == 46)
                {      
                   return false;
                }                 
                if (points == 1) 
                {
                    var lastdigits = val.substring(val.indexOf(".") + 1, val.length);
                    if (lastdigits.length >= 2)
                    {
                        alert("Two decimal places only allowed");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Only Numarics allowed");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtHDLLevel" MaxLength="6" runat="server" Width="33px" onkeypress="return numericValidation(this);"  />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Posting the solution is good, but it might improve your answer if you describe or highlight what the mistake was.

Answer (score 0):

This function will prevent entry of anything other than numbers and a single dot.

```js
function validateQty(el, evt) {
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode != 45 && charCode != 8 && (charCode != 46) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    if (charCode == 46) {
        if ((el.value) && (el.value.indexOf('.') >= 0))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return true;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var number = evt.value.split('.');
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress='return validateQty(this,event);'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for multiple text fileds (using class selector):

[Click here for example..](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAJJPB9C6DVA)

```js
var checking = function(event){
 var data = this.value;
 if((event.charCode>= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode== 46 ||event.charCode == 0){
  if(data.indexOf('.') > -1){
    if(event.charCode== 46)
      event.preventDefault();
  }
 }else
  event.preventDefault();
 };

 function addListener(list){
  for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
      list[i].addEventListener('keypress',checking);
     }
 }
 var classList = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
 addListener(classList);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" class="number" value="" /><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="number" value="" /><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="number" value="" /><br><br>
  <input type="text" class="number" value="" /><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

**Javascript**

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)&&(charCode!=46)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Usage**

```
 <input onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/Javascript">
        function checkDecimal(inputVal) {
            var ex = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/;
            if (ex.test(inputVal.value) == false) {
                inputVal.value = inputVal.value.substring(0, inputVal.value.length - 1);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function there is an error while editing it when I have added 2 digits(I have defined it's limit 2) after decimal point than it returns false, like if we have to change 1486.00 to 1582.00 without clearing the whole input or deleting any number after decimal point it will return false.

There is a small change required, where the condition of count is 1(count === 1) there add a condition `event.target.selectionStart > amount.indexOf(".")`

The final code will be

```
const validDecimal = (event) => {

    if ((event.charCode > 47 && event.charCode < 58) || event.charCode === 46) {
        var amount = event.target.value;
        var present = 0;
        var count = 0;

        do {
            present = amount.indexOf(".", present);
            if (present != -1) {
                count++;
                present++;
            }
        } while (present != -1);
        if (present === -1 && amount.length === 0 && event.charCode === 46) {
            event.charCode = 0;
            // alert("Wrong position of decimal point not  allowed !!");
            return false;
        }

        if (count >= 1 && event.charCode === 46) {
            event.charCode = 0;
            // alert("Only one decimal point is allowed !!");
            return false;
        }
        if (count === 1 && event.target.selectionStart > amount.indexOf(".")) {
            var lastdigits = amount.substring(
                amount.indexOf(".") + 1,
                amount.length
            );
            if (lastdigits.length >= 2) {
                // alert("Two decimal places only allowed");
                event.charCode = 0;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        event.charCode = 0;
        // alert("Only Numbers with dot allowed !!");
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. this could help you to solve it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
function fnAllowNumbersAndDotKey(input, event) 
{
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 46) 
    {
        //only one dot (.) allow
        if (input.value.indexOf('.') === -1)
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' >
  <input type="text" name='amount' class='form-control' onkeypress="return fnAllowNumbersAndDotKey(this, event);" maxlength="50" />
</form>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="odometer_reading" name="odometer_reading"  placeholder="Odometer Reading" onblur="odometer_reading1();" onkeypress='validate(event)' required="" />
<script>
                function validate(evt) {
                  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
                  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
                  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
                  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
                  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
                    theEvent.returnValue = false;
                    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
                  }
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Hope this could help someone

```
$(document).on("input", ".numeric", function() {
this.value = this.value.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}/);});
```